# Define a Spark scala UDF with Option as input param

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Wrote the following UDF in the aim to make it handle the case one param is not defined . 
Below is the code:

```
val addTimeFromCols: UserDefinedFunction = udf((year: String, month: String, day: String, hour: String) => {
      Option(hour) match {
        case None    => (List(year, month, day).mkString(DASH_SEP)).concat(SPACE).concat(defaultHour)
        case Some(x) => (List(year, month, day).mkString(DASH_SEP)).concat(SPACE).concat(hour)
      }
    })

 def addTimestampFromFileCols(): DataFrame = df
  .withColumn(COLUMN_TS, addTimeFromCols(col(COLUMN_YEAR), col(COLUMN_MONTH), col(COLUMN_DAY), col(COLUMN_HOUR)).cast(TimestampType))
```

My aim is to make this function applicable for all use cases ( dataframe having HOUR columns and others which won't have this col in this case I am defining a value by default. Unfortunately  this is not wotking when I test againt a dataframe which doesn't have the column I am getting the following error :

```
cannot resolve '`HOUR`' given input columns
```

Any idea how to fix this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column doesn't exist, then you must supply a default value through lit() function, otherwise it will throw error. The following worked for me

```
scala> defaultHour
res77: String = 00

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def addTimestampFromFileCols(df:DataFrame) =
{
val hr = if( df.columns.contains("hour") ) col(COLUMN_HOUR) else lit(defaultHour)
df.withColumn(COLUMN_TS, addTimeFromCols(col(COLUMN_YEAR), col(COLUMN_MONTH), col(COLUMN_DAY), hr).cast(TimestampType))
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

addTimestampFromFileCols: (df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala>
```

**+ve case**

```
scala> val df = Seq(("2019","01","10","09")).toDF("year","month","day","hour")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [year: string, month: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> addTimestampFromFileCols(df).show(false)
+----+-----+---+----+-------------------+
|year|month|day|hour|tstamp             |
+----+-----+---+----+-------------------+
|2019|01   |10 |09  |2019-01-10 09:00:00|
+----+-----+---+----+-------------------+
```

**-ve case**

```
scala> val df = Seq(("2019","01","10")).toDF("year","month","day")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [year: string, month: string ... 1 more field]

scala> addTimestampFromFileCols(df).show(false)
+----+-----+---+-------------------+
|year|month|day|tstamp             |
+----+-----+---+-------------------+
|2019|01   |10 |2019-01-10 00:00:00|
+----+-----+---+-------------------+

scala>
```